# How to show text in Page Footer on condition depends on Group value

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a *JasperReports* jrxml in which a group's datarow span across multiple pages say 10 pages.

Now, what I want is, in the page footer of first 9 pages, there should be a static text like "Continued on next page" and it should not be there on 10th page ie last page of group.

How can I do it in *JasperReports*?

Answer (score 0):

That is the tricky one. :)

You got a "print when expression" property of text fields. Create textfield with Your info, and set "print when expression" to something like:

```
$V{test} == $V{PAGE_NUMBER}
```

where $V{test} is:

```
<variable name="test" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Page">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

And set the Evaluation Time of that textfield to 'auto'. It should do the trick.

Comment: It didnt worked for me. Text field was not displaying at all on any page.

Comment: Hehe, yeah. It should be == not !=. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea. You can use pageFooter for pages 1 to 9 and lastPageFooter for page 10

```
<pageFooter>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="20"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Continued on next page]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
<lastPageFooter>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="20"/>
            <text><![CDATA[last page of group]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</lastPageFooter>
```